# Azure dev ops creating pipeline using specific folder at github

Tags: azure, azure-devops

When creating a pipeline on dev.azure.com, how do you select a specific folder at Github. For example:
https://github.com/username/projectname/tree/main/frontend.

I don't want to use the https://github.com/username/projectname/tree/main, but only the *frontend* folder.

I got the backend and frontend in the same github project, but I only need to create a pipeline for the angular frontend to create a static website.

I tried google and everything, but can't find the answer.

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

Comment: Did you look at the documentation for YAML pipelines? It explains how to limit triggers to specific folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- script: |
    cd ./frontend
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```